# Embed the code on the page and fire the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a few a tags with the name video_button_a

```
<a id="first_video" class="video_button_a" href="#"></a>
<a id="second_video" class="video_button_a" href="#"></a>
```

When I click on any of these links i need to embed this in between

```
<embed 
src="http://reelworks.net/player.swf" 
width="480"
height="200"
allowscriptaccess="always"
allowfullscreen="true"
flashvars="swfMovie=http://www.reelworks.net/video/runningsahara400x200.flv&swfThumb=http://www.reelworks.net/video/green.jpg&play_btn_scale=.65&playover_color=d7d3c0&playbk_alpha=.65&playbk_color=d7d3c0&play_color=1a1a1a',"
/>
```

I was thinking append but i didnt know the syntax

```
$('.video_button_a').click(function(){
    // code goes here 
});
```

Is append the way to go and if so how do I start the video, is there a way to put that code on the page and start the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.video_button_a').click(function(){
    $('#player').html('<embed src="http://reelworks.n.... />');
    //return false (if you want to)
});
```

I don't know if you want to embed the code inside the "a" tag which I don't think it is a good idea since it is a flash video - that is why i have a "player" id for a separate div. You could also create something like this:

```
html
<div id="first_video" class="video_button_div"></div>
<div id="second_video" class="video_button_div"></div>

js
$('.video_button_div').one('click', function() {
    $(this).html('<embed src="http://reelworks.n.... />');
    //return false (if you want to)
});

css
.video_button_div {
    cursor:pointer;
    //etc
}
```

I hope this helps!